# Why does new Array(3) function not return 3 undefined values in an Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, map-function

I am trying to create multiple `div` tags based on the value passed on to the function. ISo to do that in the function I create a `new Array(x)`, Supposedly it should create an Array with x number of undefined pointers. But while `console.log(theArray)`. It shows [empty * x] rather than undefined 3 times.

```
myFunction(value){
let myArray=new Array(value).map((_,key) => <div key={key}> Hi There</div>)
return myArray;
```

In the above function, suppose if I pass value =3, I expect myArray to contain 3 div tags with Hi There value.
Instead it returns [empty *3].

Please tell me why is that?

Comment: well, your script gives me a error

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd because it's not valid javascript syntax. It's [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at how `Array.prototype.map` is implemented under the hood by taking a look at the polyfill, you would see that there is a check for the index of iteration during the iteration of the given array before invoking the mapping callback.

So for an array having only undefined values the check for the index in the given array returns `false`:

```js
console.log(0 in [, , ]); // prints false

console.log(0 in [1, 2, 3]); //prints true
```

So the if condition cheeking the index is not satisfied and the callback you supplied is never executed so you get back a new array having `len` number of undefined values.

This is the snippet of code from the `map` polyfill:

```
//k is the index
k = 0;
//len is the length of the array
while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;
      //O is the array and this condition will be false
      if (k in O) { 

        kValue = O[k];
        //your callback will be called here
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
        //a new array is populated with the mapped value and returned
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      k++;
}
```

The `Array.prototype.map` polyfill can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).

To prevent this you can use `Array.prototype.fill` to fill the array with a value before invoking the `map`:

```js
function myFunction(value){
  let myArray = new Array(value).fill(0).map((_,key) => `<div key={key}> Hi There</div>`);
  return myArray;
}
console.log(myFunction(3));
```

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. fill(0) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Array iteration methods won't loop over array indices that are holes

You could use `Array#from()` and it's built in mapper

```
let myArray=Array.from({length:value},(_,key) => <div key={key}> Hi There</div>)
```